# scale along a vector in new coordinate system

Tags: math, matrix, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

[image]

I want to use V1 to scale something in the 2nd coordinates, but I don't know how to calculate V1', the first coordinates use Transform T to the 2nd coordinate.

what should I do?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly,
V1' = V * T<sup>-1</sup>

where T<sup>-1</sup> is inverse matrix to transform T

About multiply order - there are both "left multiply" and "right multiply" conventions. Vectors for them are row and column. And transformation matrices are transposed. For example, DirectX and OpenGL use different conventions. I don't know what one is used in cocos.

Comment: The term "reverse matrix" is not correct.   Do you mean _inverse_, or _transpose_?    [also I'm a little rusty, but surely `V1' = T * V` ?]

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks, inverse is correct term. I consider V1' point coordinates in new system and T is matrix to transform XYZ to X'Y'Z'

Comment: I saw the rotation order is ZYX for transform T, actually I've tred V* T[upper]-1[/upper], not working correct.  I think I have to calculate the rotation matrix by rotation order XYZ, then the matrix would be called T[upper]-1[upper].